# Riemann sum limits almost everywhere to the integral for $L^2$ functions on the circle

Tags: fourier-series, riemann-sum

Here is problem 1.4.7 from Dym and Mckean's Fourier Series and Integrals:
Let $I(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1/n \sum_0 ^{n-1} f(x+k/n)$ where $f \in L_2[0,1)$ and $f$ is interpreted to be periodic i.e. $f(x) = f(x+1)$ and the limit is taking place in $L_2[0,1)$.

Show $I(x) = \int f(y) dy $ almost everywhere.

The hint says to compute the fourier coefficients of the sum, which I did, but I think I'm making a mistake.

Consider the $m$th coefficient of the sum $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x+ k/n)$ which is $\frac{1}{n} \sum \int f(x + k/n) e^{ - 2 \pi i m x} dx$. Doing a substitution, I rewrite this as $\frac{1}{n} \sum \int f(u) e^{- 2 \pi i m u} e^{2 \pi i k m /n } du = \frac{1}{n} \hat{f}(m)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{2 \pi i k m/n }$ (where $\hat {f}(m)$ is the $m$th fourier coefficient of $f$)

This can be simplified $\hat{f}(m) \frac{1}{n} \frac{1 - (e^{2 \pi i m/n})^n}{1 - e^{2 \pi i m/n}} =\hat{f}(m)  \frac {1}{n} \frac{1 - e^{2 \pi i m}}{1 - e^{2 \pi i m/n}}$

Taking the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$, the $m$th fourier coefficient of our Riemman sum expression is $\hat{f}(m) \frac{1 - e^{2 \pi i m}}{ - 2 \pi i m}$ using the fact $e^{2 \pi i m/n} \approx 1 + 2 \pi i m/n$

This certainly is not zero, so the just the fact that the sum can have nonzero fourier coefficents means that it is not everywhere constant and a fortiori not equal to $\int f(y) dy$

Can you see where I went wrong?

Comment: You are using L'hospital's rule in some sense to evaluate the limit, but that is true only for real valued functions. An alternative way to look at the sum of exponentials is to look at it as the riemann sum of the function e^2πimx. You get the limit which is integral of the above function is zero.

Comment: @guest Yes this thought did pass through my mind for an instance but I dismissed it as a minor technicality. I'll think more about why this step is invalid.

Comment: @random123 I don't see where the limit computation requires the assumption that the sequence is real.

Comment: I think the exchange of limits and integrals is valid. Because the function I is nothing but the integral of a banach valued function. Then we are applying the linear functional f goes to f^(m) to it. This is same as evaluation at the functional and then the integral. One can look at appendix in the book An introduction to harmonic analysis by katz nelson for the summary of such results.

Comment: I never said fourier transform. I talked about the functional on L^2 which takes f to f^(m). This is a continuous functional.

Comment: @random123  All right, I got what you are saying.  You are correct about the exchange of limit and integral.

Comment: Thank you. Also it is true that the evaluation of limit is wrong. The limit is nothing but the riemann integral of e^(2πimx) which is certainly zero unless m =0. This is what is desired.

Comment: @random123 Okay so it looks like my mistake boils down to the computation of the limit. Viewing it as a Riemann sum, I do see that it's 0, but then where did my computation go wrong? It seems I only used the algebraic identity for finite geometric sums which is certainly true for complex numbers. And then doing a power series expansion $e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2 ....$ for the denominator and plugging $x = 2 \pi m /n $ seems to finish the computation with no issues.

Comment: I am sorry but i maybe wrong with saying that the limit you took was wrong. Here m is an integer so e^(2πim) =1. Right? So no need to take the limits. If m=0 then the sum if just f^(m). Ok?

Comment: Wow yes! I didn't recognize $e^{2 \pi i m}$ as $1$!

Comment: I am so profoundly embarrassed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @random123 for noting that $e^{2 \pi i m} = 1$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$!

It is especially funny in retrospect when I said "$\hat{f}(m) \frac{1 - e^{2 \pi i m}}{ - 2 \pi i m}$ ... is certainly not zero..."

To finish, note that for $m = 0$, the expression $\frac{1}{n} \sum \int f(u) e^{- 2 \pi i m u} e^{2 \pi i k m /n } du$ yields $\frac {1} {n} \sum \int f(u) du = \int f(u) du$. Hence the only term that contributes to the fourier series is $\int f(u) du$ multiplied against the basis vector $e^0 = 1$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll elaborate